# Most optimal way of writing sparse array not using any libraries nor hash table

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, sparse-matrix

> You are given a large array where the vast majority of the elements are zero. Create a class that can store these elements more space efficiently. Your class must have the following methods:
>
> - `constructor(originalArr)` - you are passed in the original array to store
> - `set(i, val)` - set the value val at index i
> - `get(i)` - get the value at index i
>
> Come up with a data structure that doesn't use a dictionary / hash table.
>
> ```
> EXAMPLE(S)
> sparseArr = new SparseArray([0, 0, 1, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 2])
> sparseArr.get(0) // returns 0
> sparseArr.set(0, 3)
> sparseArr.get(0) // returns 3
> sparseArr.get(2) // returns 1
>
>
> FUNCTION SIGNATURE
> class SparseArray:
>   constructor(original)
>   set(i, val)
>   get(i)
> ```

I was thinking of having three arrays, non_zero_arr, non_zero_indices_arr, and zero_indices_arr but when I thought of a case where zero value is set to non zero, I'd use binary search in zero_indices_arr to find whether the given index is present in zero_indices_arr, delete the index from the array(using the array slicing?) find the position in the non_zero_indices_arr by binary searching again, then use array slicing adding to place the new updated index and use the its index in non_zero_indices_arr to update its non_zero_value inside non_zero_arr by using array slicing again.

I guess the time complexity for each operations would be

O(n) for constructor [for logging indices, zeros, and non zeros in the appropriately named arrays]

O(log n) for get [for binary searching indices either in non_zero or zero indices array]

O(log n + n) [searching then slicing array and possibly adding updated values]

but to me this feels like a bit messy or gritty. Is there more optimal cleaner way to do it? Given this was an interview problem? Please feel free to correct my train of thought or suggest your optimal solution and a time complexity.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The requirement says it must be more space efficient. It doesn't say anything about time complexity. A linked list that you search sequentially would satisfy that.

Comment: The `scipy.sparse` package has several storage formats, with enough information in the docs to at least construct the arrays, and examine the main attributes.  `coo` is conceptually the simplest, `csr` is optimized for calculations (especially matrix multiplication). `lil` is also easy to understand.  `dok` is dictionary based.  Code to create a sparse matrix from a dense one is not trivial (though `np.nonzero` is good starting point).  Formats are also described in books and articles, including Wiki.

Comment: There isn't one "optimal" way - either for memory use, speed or easy of use.  That's part of why `scipy.sparse` provides several formats, and tools to easily convert between them.  The docs explain the intended uses.

Comment: The combination of the ban on using a hash table, the syntax error `new SparseArray(...)`, and the decision to define `get` and `set` instead of `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` makes me think this assignment was written by someone who would prefer to be teaching using Java than Python.

Comment: So there are no requirements about time complexity??

Comment: In `scipy.sparse` `coo` format (3 arrays with data, row and column indices) is simplest.  But it does not implement indexing (get/set)., in part because there's no constraint on the ordering of the nonzero terms.  `lil` is better for accessing individual elements, whether 0 or not.

Comment: @Barmar, yeah. Thanks for the suggestion. Linked list sounds great.

Comment: @chepner, I did write python in the title, in case anyone was going to write codes to demonstrate.

Comment: Another thought - the `scipy` formats, especially `coo` and `csr` were developed for large 2d arrays (matrices), the kind that might be used to model large linear systems (finite difference or finite element).  If your array is 1d, where two arrays would be sufficient (values and indices), things are, potentially, much simpler.

Comment: It's unspecific and does not fit in SO. Anyway, I'll say my opinion. The problem is for 1D arrays. So it's meaningless to talk about formats COO, CSR, LIL, etc.(They are for matrices). The problem is for arrays, hinting a requirement for decent random access performance. So a linked list is not an option. Then most popular choice will be a binary search. So you took the right track. But you only need arrays for nonzero values and their indices. Look at [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java).

Comment: B-tree or B+-tree will perform well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many data structures that can deal with these requirements, including:

- [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), [B+tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree)
- [Skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)
- Self-balancing binary search trees, like [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL), [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)...

Another one, is a [bitwise trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Bitwise_tries).

Here is a barebones bitwise trie implementation where each node deals with just one bit of the given index, so it is a *binary* tree. The height of the tree will be equal to the number of bits in the binary representation of the greatest index that the data structure has to store a value for.

```
class SparseArray:
    def __init__(self, original=None):
        self.height = self.tree = 0
        if original:
            for i, val in enumerate(original):
                if val:
                    self.set(i, val)
    
    def remove(self, i):
        def recur(node, shift, i):
            j = (i >> shift) & 1
            node[j] = shift and recur(node[j], shift - 1, i & ((1 << shift) - 1))
            return node if any(node) else 0
        
        if i.bit_length() <= self.height:
            self.tree = recur(self.tree, self.height - 1, i)
            # Reduce height if possible
            if self.tree != 0:
                while self.height > 1 and self.tree[1] == 0:
                    self.height -= 1
                    self.tree = self.tree[0]
            else:
                self.height = 0
                
    def set(self, i, val):
        if val == 0:  # We don't store zeroes...
            return self.remove(i)
        # Increase tree height if this index needs more bits
        width = i.bit_length()
        if self.height < width and self.tree != 0:
            for _ in range(self.height, width):
                self.tree = [self.tree, 0]
        self.height = max(width, self.height)
        # Drill down
        if not self.tree:
            self.tree = [0]*2
        node = self.tree
        for bit in range(self.height - 1, 0, -1):
            side = (i >> bit) & 1
            if node[side] == 0:
                node[side] = [0]*2
            node = node[side]
        node[i & 1] = val  # Set leaf's value
                
    def get(self, i):
        node = self.tree
        if i.bit_length() > self.height:  # Out of current range
            return 0
        node = self.tree
        for bit in range(self.height - 1, 0, -1):
            side = (i >> bit) & 1
            node = node[side]
            if node == 0:  # No subtree here
                return 0
        return node[i & 1]  # Get leaf's value

    def items(self):
        def recur(node, i):
            if isinstance(node, list):
                yield from recur(node[0], i*2)
                yield from recur(node[1], i*2+1)
            elif node != 0:
                yield i, node
            
        yield from recur(self.tree, 0)
```

The worst case space complexity is O(), where  is the number of non-zero values stored in the sparse array, and  is the number of bits in the binary representation of the greatest index that is used for a non-zero value. An example of a worst case is when all indices are sequential powers of 2.

The best case space complexity is O(). This is when the binary tree is perfect, which means there are no gaps in the array (it is not sparse).

The time complexity of `get` and `set` is O().

#### Improvements

Performance will improve when a node gets a greater branching factor (instead of 2) and thus deals with a larger chunk of bits instead of just 1. Like 4 bits.

There exist several variants that improve on memory and speed. See for instance [bitwise tree with bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_trie_with_bitmap), including the CTPOP bit-hack implementation.